# Extract UIImage with path

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

How can i extract an UIImage with an path?

I need to get the content that's inside the path into a new UIImage. What I need is the content of a rotated rectangle. This is the code that I use to get the corners of the rectangle. (x,y = center of image. width, height of image).

```
UIBezierPath* aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

//1
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(
                               x+(width/2)*cosf(A)-(height/2)*sinf(A),
                               y+(height/2)*cosf(A)+(width/2)*sinf(A))];

NSLog(@"%f, %f", x+(width/2)*cosf(A)-(height/2)*sinf(A),
      y+(height/2)*cosf(A)+(width/2)*sinf(A));


//2
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(
                               x-(width/2)*cosf(A)-(height/2)*sinf(A),
                               y+(height/2)*cosf(A)-(width/2)*sinf(A))];

NSLog(@"%f, %f", x-(width/2)*cosf(A)-(height/2)*sinf(A),
      y+(height/2)*cosf(A)-(width/2)*sinf(A));


//3
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(
                               x-(width/2)*cosf(A)+(height/2)*sinf(A),
                               y-(height/2)*cosf(A)-(width/2)*sinf(A))];

NSLog(@"%f, %f", x-(width/2)*cosf(A)+(height/2)*sinf(A),
      y-(height/2)*cosf(A)-(width/2)*sinf(A));


//4
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(
                               x+(width/2)*cosf(A)+(height/2)*sinf(A),
                               y-(height/2)*cosf(A)+(width/2)*sinf(A))];

NSLog(@"%f, %f", x+(width/2)*cosf(A)+(height/2)*sinf(A),
      y-(height/2)*cosf(A)+(width/2)*sinf(A));



//5
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(
                               x+(width/2)*cosf(A)-(height/2)*sinf(A),
                               y+(height/2)*cosf(A)+(width/2)*sinf(A))];

NSLog(@"%f, %f", x+(width/2)*cosf(A)-(height/2)*sinf(A),
      y+(height/2)*cosf(A)+(width/2)*sinf(A));
[aPath closePath];
```

I was thinking something like this: [A picture of the problem.](http://i50.tinypic.com/30nhpnb.png)
(The shape is different here.) I want that yellow part to be a new UIImage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your `UIBezierPath` as a clipping path. There is the `addClip` method for that.

See [the Quartz2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html), especially [this part](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF126) for details.

The idea is to create a new Bitmap context, apply the clipping using your path, then draw the image (that will thus get clipped) on this bitmap context and finally generate an UIImage from it.

*Moreover, instead of making some maths by yourself to rotate your `CGRect` you want to use for clipping, you should create a `CGRect` without any rotation, and use `CGAffineTransform` to rotate it. This will avoid the need to do the computation by yourself using `cos`/`sin` functions and make your code easier to read.*

---

[EDIT] Here is a full example to:

- Generate a Bezier path and apply CGAffineTransform rotation to it
- Use this bezier path to clip an image

I did check it and works like a charm.

```
// Generate a UIBezierPath of a rounded rect rotated by angle radians
-(UIBezierPath*)computePathWithRect:(CGRect)rect
                       cornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius
                              angle:(CGFloat)radians;
{
  // Compute basic path
  UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:cornerRadius];

  // Apply rotation.
  // Don't forget that rotations are around origin 0,0 so if you want to rotate around the rect's center,
  // you need to apply a translation so that the rect's center is at 0,0, then rotate, and translate it back at its original position.
  CGAffineTransform restoreCenterPosition = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
  CGAffineTransform rotateFromOrigin = CGAffineTransformRotate(restoreCenterPosition,radians);
  CGAffineTransform rotateFromRectCenter = CGAffineTransformTranslate(rotateFromOrigin, -CGRectGetMidX(rect), -CGRectGetMidY(rect));
  [path applyTransform:rotateFromRectCenter];

  return path;
}

// Generate a new image from srcImage but clipped with the given path
-(UIImage*)clipImage:(UIImage*)srcImage withPath:(UIBezierPath*)path
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(srcImage.size, NO, 0.0);

  // Add clipping path
  // Actually UIBezierPath has a method for that, that is equivalent to CGContextClip(currentContext, bezierPath.CGPath), so better use it
  [path addClip];

  // Flip coordinates before drawing image as UIKit and CoreGraphics have inverted coordinate system
  CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, srcImage.size.height);
  CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1, -1);
  // Draw image, that will thus be clipped, on the bitmap context
  CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, srcImage.size.width, srcImage.size.height), srcImage.CGImage);

  // Generate final (clipped) image
  UIImage* clippedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return clippedImage;
}


// Usage example
- (void)doClipping
{
  UIImage* originalImage = ...
  UIBezierPath* path = [self computePathWithRect:CGRectMake(100,100,184,94)
                                    cornerRadius:10.f
                                           angle:30*M_PI/180.f];
  UIImage* clippedImage = [self clipImage:originalImage withPath:path];
  self.resultImageView.image = clippedImage;
}
```

Comment: Note that I haven't tested my code, just wrote it directly from the Apple documentation and the quoted Programming Guide. Feel free to adapt.

Comment: Right now it returns a blank image. But i'll figure it out soon :)

Comment: Could you try to update your question so it works? I've tried but I just can't get it to work :( I'd really, really appreciate that.

Comment: I forgot that you have to flip the coordinates before drawing your image as UIKit and CoreGraphics have inverted coordinates. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: you are the king! It works so smooth! I'd give you a hug if I saw you, haha! Thanks!